# Meaning of identity tag

Tags: manmade-object-identification

Does anyone know the meaning of this tag?

While wandering in the UK's great outdoors today, I found a chain with several objects attached, including this tag.

I found it on the ground, so I hung it on the lee side of a nearby tree where the loser would easily see it when retracing their steps, by a gate they would have to pass through.

[image]

Does anyone know what it means?

Comment: Could it be a geo-cache reference?

Comment: could it be a sort of medic alert? O positive blood type, last line None referring to allergies? The number an id in that system, Hartop a last name? H W D could, if these are standard issue say from military, identify their unit? Hants West Division kind of thing.

Comment: @KateGregory good spot thanks.

Comment: @KateGregory the top result of a Google Lens images search turned up [Graphotype Personalised dot peen marked British forces dog tags](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Graphotype-Personalised-marked-British-forces/dp/B08P55P8T8).

Comment: hm, chain matches. Sample has CE on the last line suggesting it's religion, not allergies.

Comment: @KateGregory it could be surname // initials.  I think the guess of military ID is looking like the best, possible genuine, though maybe military style.  My own earlier ideas were almost certainly a red herring and I'll tidy them up at some point - leaving them now so no one wastes time on it independently

Comment: I phoned the UK MOD who transferred me to the nearby RAF station, who said that they could only put the item into their lost property system (UK police no longer do that), or I they could do a local search of their personnel. So tomorrrow I will return to the site and if the item is still where I left it I will take it to the RAF base to see if they can ID it. Thanks everyone. There was something rather nice on the chain which I am sure they would not want to lose.

Comment: I've tidied up my earlier comments.  In summary, it's not an OS grid ref.  If it was, it wouldn't be unique

Comment: @ChrisH thanks for your input. I've moved some detail into the question and deleted some comments.

Comment: I presume CE = Church of England.

Answer (score 6):

**Result**: the item was still hanging where I left it yesterday.

A Google Lens search turned up a tag on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Graphotype-Personalised-marked-British-forces/dp/B08P55P8T8) that is very similar to this one, which British Forces personnel seem to like to buy.

[image]

I followed up the idea that the person has a military connection and visited a nearby base. They do have someone of that name there, an unusual name that I've not heard before.

Today is Sunday and the reception only has an extension number so I logged it in as 'lost property' for them to follow up tomorrow. But I'm confident it's a hit, due to the unusual name. If not, it'll go through the military police system.

One strange thing is that I *know the security person who was on duty* but had no idea that was their job.

Comment: A corroborative detail is that a lovely clockwork pocket watch attached to the chain was slightly feminine in design. And the person bearing that name is female. There were other items on the chain, too.